# What are field lines?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

What are field lines and how come they relate to both electrical systems and magnetic systems?

Separately, what do North and South poles have to do with all of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Electric and magnetic fields are three components fields, i.e. vector fields (even if of two different types).
So, for each spacepoint, you have an arrow that is pointing in some direction.

Field lines are *field integral curves*, i.e. they are a set of curves that fills the whole space (each point of the space belongs to a certain field line) that has in each point the direction pointed by the field as the tangential one.

Stated differently: field lines are the unique set of lines that fills the whole space whose tangent directions coincides in each point with the direction of the field.

**EDIT**

it’s only a clarification: pay attention that given a field the field lines are unique, but given the set of field lines the fields is not unique, because it misses the information on “how fast you are travelling” on the line (the field lines are trajectories of point particle if the field is a velocity field).

So field lines retain the information on the direction of the field, but not of its module (to keep that information you’ve to give a *parametrization* of each line, in the case of velocity field you have to specify the function $\overrightarrow{x}(t)$ and not only its graphic)

Comment: Does that mean that magnets create field lines because the opposite sides are of opposite charge? If so, how come this charge doesn’t flow through the magnet?

Comment: In the electric anologue of what you’re saying the answer is yes, if you have a way to fix to charges of opposite signs on a the two sides of a stick (truly possible) field lines are as the one of a magnet. But magnetic charge (monopoles) for now are unobserved, so you haveto think that the basical unit of magnets are dipoles, with a north and a south pole, indivisible and unmixable, and if you put a lot of those unit aligned you obtain an ordinary magnet, but already each of that are magnets themselves

Comment: What really happens it’s more complicated, and magnetism is due to the electrons that orbit in the atoms https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paramagnetism#Pauli_paramagnetism https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_quantization#Landau_levels http://physics.ucsc.edu/~peter/231/magnetic_field/node5.html